# Getting all my events from api route events with ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

currently i'm trying to catch all my events in my database by the 'events' route, and is working, but i have some doubts about how it works.

**Please, observe all the names.**

So,  i have this route, which will call the events route:

```
SiteApp.EventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    this.store.findAll('event');
 }
});
```

Here, i'm using the EventSSSSSS, with S.

But my model needs to be without the S:

```
SiteApp.Event = DS.Model.extend(
  description : DS.attr()
  name        : DS.attr()
  type        : DS.attr()
)
```

If i try to use with S and call `this.store.findAll('events');` will throw this strange error:

```
Error while processing route: events Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push' Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push'
```

Why can't i use EventS in all? The framework is so amazing, but the documentation is very poor, and i'm not finding resources to understand the conventions...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an adapter for the events model

```
ember g adapter event
```

The convention is to look for the pluralized version of words, so in the file you just created, you need to tell ember to look for the singular version of the word.

```
  pathForType() {
    return 'event'
  }
```

Check out the [Ember guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-adapters/) for more info.

Comment: So it's normal declare the models in singular? I was thinking that i was doing wrong.

Comment: Nope convention is to declare models as singular, when Ember does an api call it will default to looking to the pluralized version.

Comment: Yup, conventions are a double edged sword, great when you know them, bad when you don't.

Comment: Hei Tyler, i'm receiving this strange return class in the findAll, do you know why? Class {__ember1443850972614: null, __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta__: Object}

Comment: From your events route, make sure to return your findAll. Other than that, not sure what's causing that, would need more information.

Comment: I update my answer! Perhaps you could checkout my code and give me some tips? I stuck in this at least for 3 days, i'm very frustrated...